# ListView item specific animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I would like to animate three items in a Listview such that the three items start off ordered as a stack where first item is on top, second one in middle and third at the bottom.The top then moves up from the top, the middle one stays and then the third slides down from behind the second. I have managed the animation but yet to figure out the z-ordering. I am applying the animations for these three items individually in the adapter, however because there is no sense of grouping between these items, the z-ordering is not maintained. Is it possible to control which child within the listview gets drawn first?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is easily doable. You can animate each row (list data line is commonly referenced as `row` not `item`), but each row will be animated the same way, so it won't meet your needs. Sure, you could probably achieve your goal, but that would require more coding. And if you got fixed number of rows (namely 3) are you sure you need list view there? Maybe build your layout with with 3 linear layouts (or anything) and then you can apply different animation to each of them separately with no hassle

Comment: No, this is a listview with more than three items, but due to the size of the items, only three are visible... I am investigating if view.bringToFront() can some how be used...

Comment: I dare to say "only three all visible" is invalid assumption. It all depends of display size. Anyway, my answer remain valid - it is easy to apply one animation to all rows (visible or not) and it will require custom code to do what you need. Evaluate if it is worth it.